# Me salta el error net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, html, sql

tengo una web con una lista desplegable que muestra una serie de códigos y según el código que seleccione se completan las cajas de texto, mi problema viene cuando selecciono uno de los códigos que en la cajas de texto me aparece **"undefined"** y en la consola del navegador me aparece el siguiente error net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, he estado buscando por Google pero no he dado con la solución.( Mi web esta alojada en 000webhost).

Pagina donde se selecciona el código

```html
<?php
//* configuracion database.
include("conexion.php");
 


function filtrado($datos){
    $datos = trim($datos); // Elimina espacios antes y después de los datos
    $datos = stripslashes($datos); // Elimina backslashes \
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos); // Traduce caracteres especiales en entidades HTML
    return $datos;
}
 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
 
.


?>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 
<head>
    <link href="CSS\style_Modificar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="CSS\Modificar_Datos_Principales.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <title>Modificar Datos Principales</title>
</head>

<body>


  <h1>MODIFICAR DATOS PRINCIPALES</h1>




<div class="Contenido">
  
<form>





<?php 
  include("conexion.php");




  $query = 'SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal';

  $result = $conexion->query($query);

?>
  <p>Código Interno</p>  
  <select id="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();" name="producto"> 

       <option value="0" > Seleccione:</option> 
    <?php    
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>
    


       <option value="<?php echo $row['Cod_Interno']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['Cod_Interno']; ?></option> 
       
        

        <?php


    }   

    ?>    
    
  </select>
<?php

?> <br>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowSelected()
{

var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value;


if(cod == '0'){

alert('Elige una opción');
return false; 

}else{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
clean = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  }else{ 
clean = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  clean.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if (clean.readyState  == 4 && clean.status == 200) {  

var respuesta = clean.responseText; 

var jsonjs = JSON.parse(respuesta);



console.log(jsonjs[0].cOficial);
console.log(jsonjs[0].gHospital);
console.log(jsonjs[0].tLocal);
console.log(jsonjs[0].tQS);
console.log(jsonjs[0].cNacional);
console.log(jsonjs[0].coAutonomico);
console.log(jsonjs[0].hSiglas);
console.log(jsonjs[0].fAlta);
console.log(jsonjs[0].fBaja);
console.log(jsonjs[0].tBaja);
console.log(jsonjs[0].cEpisodio);




document.getElementById('Centrooficial').value = jsonjs[0].cOficial;

document.getElementById('GrupoHospital').value = jsonjs[0].gHospital;

document.getElementById('TipoLocal').value = jsonjs[0].tLocal;

document.getElementById('TerritorioQS').value = jsonjs[0].tQS;

document.getElementById('CodigoNacional').value = jsonjs[0].cNacional;

document.getElementById('CodigoOficialAutonomico').value = jsonjs[0].coAutonomico;

document.getElementById('Siglas').value = jsonjs[0].hSiglas;

document.getElementById('FechaAlta').value = jsonjs[0].fAlta;

document.getElementById('FechaBaja').value = jsonjs[0].fBaja;

document.getElementById('TipoBaja').value = jsonjs[0].tBaja;

document.getElementById('CodigoEpisodio').value = jsonjs[0].cEpisodio;



}

}

clean.open('GET','Consulta_Datos_Principales.php?cod='+cod,true);

clean.send();
 
}
}

</script>

  Nombre Centro Oficial
  <input type="textbox" name="Centrooficial" id="Centrooficial"><br>

  Grupo Hospital
  <input type="textbox" name="GrupoHospital" id="GrupoHospital"><br>

  Tipo Local
  <input type="textbox" name="TipoLocal" id="TipoLocal"><br>

  Territorio QS
  <input type="textbox" name="TerritorioQS" id="TerritorioQS"><br>

  Código Nacional
  <input type="textbox" name="CodigoNacional" id="CodigoNacional"><br>

  Código Ofical Autonómico
  <input type="textbox" name="CodigoOficialAutonomico" id="CodigoOficialAutonomico"><br>

  Siglas
  <input type="textbox" name="Siglas" id="Siglas"><br>

  Fecha Alta
  <input type="textbox" name="FechaAlta" id="FechaAlta"><br>

  Fecha Baja
  <input type="textbox" name="FechaBaja" id="FechaBaja"><br>

  Tipo Baja
  <input type="textbox" name="TipoBaja" id="TipoBaja"><br>

  Código Episodio
  <input type="textbox" name="CodigoEpisodio" id="CodigoEpisodio" ><br>  

  <br> 

  <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Grabar" /> 

</form>


</div>

</body>



</html>
```

Pagina donde se realiza la consulta para devolver los valores

```html
<?php


$codigo = $_GET['cod']; 



include("conexion.php");





$query = "SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal WHERE Cod_Interno = '$codigo'  ";



$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query)or die ('Fallo al realizar la consulta');




$datos = array(['Centrooficial' => $row[0],
    'GrupoHospital' => $row[1],
    'TipoLocal' => $row[2],
    'TerritorioQS' => $row[3],
    'CodigoNacional' => $row[4],
    'CodigoOficialAutonomico' => $row[5],
    'Siglas' => $row[6],
    'FechaAlta' => $row[7],
    'FechaBaja' => $row[8],
    'TipoBaja' => $row[9],
    'CodigoEpisodio' => $row[10]

]);



echo json_encode($datos);



?>
```

Comment: En tu consulta usas $row pero no parece estar definida. Me temo que te falta el fetch del resultado de la query. Aparte esa consulta es muy pero que muy vulnerable a inyección sql.

Comment: ¿Podrías confirmar qué archivos son los que te producen ese error mirando en la consola de depuración en la pestaña del tráfico de red? ¿Has probado a llamar al mismo PHP desde el navegador agregando el parámetro deseado a la URL? A parte de lo que dice @JDev acerca de la definición de `$row` y de la inyección SQL, un error de conexión no debería ser una respuesta habitual del servidor a tu consulta XHR por muchos errores que tenga tu código.

Comment: He mirado donde me has indicado OscarGarcia y el error que me indica es este Request URL: https://anhubnew.info/i.js?tag=ww_60_2&did=1&v_tag=84817&k_tag=0

Comment: Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar el error, cuando en el navedaor me voy a la pestaña Source de la consola me marca como fallo la siguiente parte del código  document.body.appendChild(script); . Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

el error de tipo `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` quiere decir que la conexión con el servidor ha muerto sin ninguna respuesta al cliente. cuando digo que ha muerto sin ninguna respuesta, me refiero que no tenemos como respuesta un error HTTP numero 5XX. Esto a causa de que un proceso de tu script de php no se ha podido cerrar correctamente.

En tu caso el error probablemente esta en tu proceso de consulta de base de datos. Sería ideal que revises los registros de errores de tu host para encontrar el problema.